# Parsing link in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

Getting some JSON with a string link to images(on the server) and want to save them on device.
To save them I have to name them, so the name of the file on the server would be perfect.
Example: I have this link `https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/882558757531791360/CGKUrcD9.jpg`
How can I get **CGKUrcD9.jpg** part of it using C# and Unity?

Comment: This is a basic question about parsing strings in C#. Programming questions which aren't specific to game development should be posted on stackoverflow.com... [if they are not already posted and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105593/get-file-name-from-uri-string-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LastIndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the position of the last antislash and use [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx) to "cut" your string after the antislash:

```
string GetFileName(string link)
{
    return link.Substring( link.LastIndexOf('/') + 1 ) ;
}
```

Comment: Otherwise, check [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105593/get-file-name-from-uri-string-in-c-sharp)